# Evaluating a sequence and its subsequences

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, sequences-and-series, limits, convergence-divergence

Evaluating the convergence of the sequence
$$(x_n)_{n=1}^\infty   =  {{\sin(\frac{\pi n}{2})\cdot n^{2}}\over {n^{2}+{1}}}$$
since $\sin( \frac{\pi n}{2})$ produces the sequence
$$ 1,0,-1,0,1,0,-1,...$$
and $0 <\frac{n^2}{n^2 +1}<1$, I can say there are subsequences $({x_{n_k}})$,$({x_{n_p}})$, $({x_{n_m}})$ such that convergence to $-1$,$0$ and $1$, respectively.

It does not exist a subsequence such that convergence to infinity, since $(x_n)$ is bounded.

Is this a valid evaluation to state that sequence $(x_n)$ diverges?

My evaluation was based on [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2442581/867073) visualization. I would like to see a more tedious evaluation on its convergence

Comment: You just need the two subsequences $ (x_{2n})$ which goes to zero and $ (x_{2n+1})$ which goes to one. You conclude that the mother sequence $(x_n)$  diverges.

Comment: If a sequence converges, then all of its subsequences converge to the same limit. Conversely, if some subsequence diverges or two converging subsequences have different limits, the sequence diverges.

Comment: @DanielEgea You did not specify what are $ n_k $  , $n_p$.

Comment: @hamam_Abdallah Subsequeces. I wanted to express that there are such subsequences that convergence to $-1$,$1$ and $0$

Comment: @DanielEgea Please Look again at my first post, the subsequences are well defined.